# Solving nonlinear ODE system with continuous Newton method

Tags: numerical-methods

Is anyone knows how to apply continuous Newton method for solving nonlinear ODE systems? For example let the system is:

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc} y'= \frac{z}{x} \\ z'= \frac{z(y+2z-1)}{x(y-1)}\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Is $x$ the dependent variable?

Comment: I think so. It's not mentioned in the text.

Comment: Could anyone can help?